# WPF | ChromiumWebBrowser address binding does not affect UI

Tags: wpf

I am trying to show a ChromiumWebBrowser that navigates between local HTML files.
I set a binding to the Address property in my VM, and it works only in the initial value.
when I set the address in ViewModel binded property (navigating with custom buttons) browser does not update.

what am I missing here?
(in Snoop I can see the address indeed changes, but view is same).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewModel class must implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and call OnPropertyChanged whenever the ViewModel property is updated.

[INotifyPropertyChanged Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)